# How to export a Highchart chart to PDF thanks to a button outside the chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, charts, highcharts

I would like to have a `button outside a Highchart chart` that `export` the chart in `PDF`.

- Does it exist a Highchart method to do that ?
- Does an ajax call is mandatory ?

### HTML :

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; margin-top: 1em"></div>
<button id="export2pdf">Export to PDF</button>
```

### Javascript :

```
$(function () {
    window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {renderTo : 'container'},
        title: {
            text: 'Exporting module is loaded but buttons are disabled'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }],
        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });

    $("#export2pdf").click(function(){
        // Export method ?
        // Ajax call ?
    });
});
```

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2M2Je/2/) of what I would like.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2M2Je/3/) with the solution of [wergeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33727/wergeld).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See the API. This is covered here under [`exportChart`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.exportChart).
Essentially do this:

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
chart.exportChart({
    type: 'application/pdf',
    filename: 'my-pdf'
});
```

Comment: The API is so large that it is sometimes difficult to find what you want/need ! ;) Thanks.

Comment: It is, but, well documented. The api is searchable - however, it needs to be exact text.

Comment: This approach works well, but for Highcharts, series[] inserted dynamically using jquery, How to execute this to export to excel. Like `var options = {
    chart : {
     renderTo : 'container',` .Can you please help?

Comment: This command does not work when exporting offline (i.e. without accessing highchart servers). I added `offline-exporting.js` and still tries to access `export.highcharts.com`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [exporting](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting) properties for Highcharts. You will want to set `type` to `application/pdf`.